# Can I create a RDLC drillthrough with Entity Framework datasource?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reporting-services, rdlc

I am using Entity Framework 6 and RDLC files for local reporting in a WinForms application.

Creating a single report is straightforward.  I define the data ViewModel for the report within my EF model, which I then use as the dataset for designing the RDLC report.

At runtime, I use LINQ to populate the data ViewModel and provide this as the datasource to the RDLC.

I now want to create a DrillThrough from one report to another.  Is this possible?

On creating a DrillThrough I can specify the report being called and pass some parameters, but that assumes the report being called uses a query as a datasource so can use the parameters being passed.

In an RDLC report with an Entity Framework datasource, the dataset is created outside of the RDLC so there is no query for the RDLC to run.

Is there a way of defining a DrillThrough action that that will call a Windows Form with a parameter or do I just need to use an SQL query as the datasource of any RDLC reports I use as drillthrough targets?

Comment: You should be able to query the SQL Server from the RDLC.  RDLC is html so make sure you replace special characters like greater than sign and less than sign with the html equivalent.

Comment: @jdweng thanks. I know I can use an SQL query as a datasource, but I was hoping to use a LINQ query against my Entity Framework model instead. Can that be done from an RDLC?

Comment: Try following code project : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/622188/RDLC-report-with-LINQ-datasource

Comment: @jdweng thanks - that project is how I am creating my RDLC reports now. The datasource is initialised externally. On a drillthrough the datasource must be created within the RDLC (I believe) so this won't work. I don't think it's possible to do what I'm asking unless I use SQL as my datasource or use a Web based solution so I can use a URL as the drillthrough action.

Comment: Isn't the rdlc http which means it is already web?

Comment: @jdweng the rdlc is XML but is rendered via a viewer (either a webform or winforms control).  I am writing a winforms application so using the WinForms Report Viewer control.